# fread(): Unable to read file for /proc/$pid/status

Tags: c, linux-kernel, segmentation-fault, fread

I am trying to read the file `/proc/$pid/status` in a function. I am able to open the file using `fopen` and when I read it using `fread()` I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

Function:

```
void getContextSwitches() {
    FILE* fp;

    int pid = getpid();
    char spid[10];
    snprintf(spid, 10, "%d", pid);

    char buffer[3000];
    size_t bytesRead;

    printf("\nPid of the process is: %s", spid);

    char path[50];
    path[0] = '\0';
    strcat(path, "/proc/");
    strcat(path, spid);
    strcat(path, "/status");

    printf("\nPath: %s\n", path);

    fp = getFile(fp, path);

    if(NULL == fp) {
        printf("File status is not read\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("File pointer not null");
    printf("size of buffer: %ld", sizeof(buffer));
    bytesRead = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), fp);
    printf("\nIt's not coming here");
    fclose(fp);
}
```

And here is the output which I obtain:

```
Pid of the process is: 85244
Path: /proc/85244/status

File pointer not null
Size of buffer: 3000
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The `buffer` size has been allocated properly and also the `fp` is not null. I have similar functionalities in other areas of my code and they work fine. I have checked the signature of `fread()` and that looks fine too.

Can someone help me understand the issue behind this?

Comment: Please include the source to getFile().

Comment: Always urn your program with AddressSanitizer, or at *least* valgrind, whenever you have (or even suspect) memory problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your `getFile()` function.
The rest of the code is OK.

I suspect you're returning an invalid `FILE*` from `getFile()`.

Comment: Likely assigning to the (useless) `FILE*` argument and returning junk.